# Can I avoid using data frames in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm running a monte-carlo simulation and the output is in the form:

```
> d = data.frame(iter=seq(1, 2), k1 = c(0.2, 0.6), k2=c(0.3, 0.4))
> d
iter  k1   k2
1     0.2  0.3
2     0.6  0.4
```

The plots I want to generate are:

```
plot(d$iter, d$k1)
plot(density(d$k1))
```

I know how to do equivalent plots using ggplot2,  convert to data frame

```
new_d = data.frame(iter=rep(d$iter, 2), 
                   k = c(d$k1, d$k2), 
                   label = rep(c('k1', 'k2'), each=2))
```

then plotting is easy. However the number of iterations can be very large and the number of k's can also be large. This means messing about with a very large data frame.

Is there anyway I can avoid creating this new data frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer is "no," you can't avoid creating a data frame. `ggplot` requires the data to be in a data frame. If you use `qplot`, you can give it separate vectors for x and y, but internally, it's still creating a data frame out of the parameters you pass in.

I agree with juba's suggestion -- learn to use the `reshape` function, or better yet the `reshape` package with `melt`/`cast` functions. Once you get fast with putting your data in long format, creating amazing `ggplot` graphs becomes one step closer!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it is possible for you to avoid creating a data frame: just give an empty argument list to the base layer, `ggplot()`. Here is a complete example based on your code:

library(ggplot2)

```
d = data.frame(iter=seq(1, 2), k1 = c(0.2, 0.6), k2=c(0.3, 0.4))
# desired plots:
# plot(d$iter, d$k1)
# plot(density(d$k1))

ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x = d$iter, y = d$k1))
# there is not enough data for a good density plot,
# but this is how you would do it:
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(d$k1))
```

Note that although this allows for *you* not to create a data frame, a data frame might still be created internally. See, e.g., the following extract from `?geom_point`:

> All objects will be fortified to produce a data frame.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `reshape` function to transform your data frame to "long" format. May be it is a bit faster than your code ?

```
R> reshape(d, direction="long",varying=list(c("k1","k2")),v.names="k",times=c("k1","k2"))
     iter time   k id
1.k1    1   k1 0.2  1
2.k1    2   k1 0.6  2
1.k2    1   k2 0.3  1
2.k2    2   k2 0.4  2
```

Answer (score 4):

So just to add to the previous answers. With qplot you could do

```
p <- qplot(y=d$k2, x=d$k1)
```

and then from there building it further, e.g. with

```
p + theme_bw()
```

But I agree - melt/cast is genereally the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass NULL as the data frame, and define the necessary aesthetics using the   data vectors. Quick example:

```
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(ranger)

rf <- ranger(medv ~ ., data = Boston, importance = "impurity")

rf$variable.importance

ggplot(NULL, aes(x = fct_reorder(names(rf$variable.importance), rf$variable.importance),
                 y = rf$variable.importance)) +
    geom_col(fill = "navy blue", alpha = 0.7) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(x = "Predictor", y = "Importance", title = "Random Forest") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image: Random Forest]